# Bootstrap and out-of-bootstrap error calculation

Tags: self-study, bootstrap, standard-error, error

I was trying to solve a question in one of the exercises in my class regarding bootstrap sampling but I am stuck with 0-idea how to move forward. The question is about bootstrapping and calculating the bootstrap and the out-of bootstrap estimates of the generalization error. There are 4 samples which are shown below;

Original Data       |Z*   | Bootstrap 1 |Bootstrap 2    |Bootstrap 3    | Bootstrap 4
Z₁----------------  Z₁*=   ---Z₄---------------    Z₅  ---------------Z₃------------   Z₃
Z₂----------------  Z₂*=   ---Z₁---------------    Z₅  ---------------Z₁------------   Z₅
Z₃----------------  Z₃*=   ---Z₄---------------    Z₂  ---------------Z₃------------   Z₂
Z₄----------------  Z₄*=   ---Z₂---------------    Z₁  ---------------Z₄------------   Z₂
Z₅----------------  Z₅*=   ---Z₁---------------    Z₃  ---------------Z₂------------   Z₃

Questions can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzcl2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the formula allows one to compute an estimate of the generalization error by averaging the error over the 4 Bootstrap data sets.

**(i)** The estimator $\hat{m}^{*(j)}$ is simply computed based on the $j^{th}$ Bootstrap set. The estimator is identical for both, the bootstrap and the out-of-bootstrap methods.

**(ii)**

- In the standard bootstrap method, we average over all bootstrap samples, i.e. $\alpha_{ij} = \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{5}$.
- For the out-of-bootstrap case, the inner sum is only over those elements that were not used for training, i.e. the elements that are not contained in $j^{th}$ bootstrap data set. Therefore, $\alpha_{ij} = 0$ if $Z_i \in \text{Bootstrap } j$ otherwise $\alpha_{ij}$ is equal $\frac{1}{\# \{\text{distinct elements in Bootstrap j\}}}$.

Comment: We already have our bootstrap samples. For Standard bootstrap case shouldn't the calculation for $\alpha_{ij}$ also depend on the drawings bootstrap sample?

Comment: No, only the estimator depends on the bootstrap samples. The bootstrap estimate for the generalization error is computed based on all training data.